# Is there a way to utilize an Oracle wallet via PHP on windows?

Tags: php, database, windows, oracle

I have a PHP codebase that resides on a Windows server that connects to an Oracle database.  My database is moving to a Oracle in the cloud setup that requires us to use an Oracle wallet to connect.

I got the setup for the wallet and can connect via the utilities, but all my research thus far has me using oci_connect() with a session_mode of OCI_CRED_EXT.  But PHP's oci_connect (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) states "OCI_CRED_EXT is not supported on Windows for security reasons.".

Is there a way to utilize an Oracle wallet via PHP on windows?

Comment: It doesn't appear to work at all in Windows. Unix only.

Comment: Known 'feature'; I'll bump it up my todo list. I understand the technical (security) constraint should no longer be a problem, but this will need some review.  The code change is [likely to be minimal](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-8.0.0/ext/oci8/oci8.c#L942-L948), perhaps replacing that code with a requirement for a minimum Oracle client library.

Comment: Christopher, I admit that I expected a whole lot of "it won't work, use unix/linux", but your response caught me off-guard.  I appreciate the encouraging response and it made my afternoon a little brighter.  I hope you and yours are staying safe and sane in these trying times.

Comment: See my answer below: I now assume you are in Oracle's Cloud and don't need external auth.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle Cloud wallets provide mutual TLS for security but you still need to pass a DB username and password.  Hence you don't use external authentication.

You just need to make sure that Oracle Net can find the wallet, either with the [Easy Connect Plus](https://download.oracle.com/ocomdocs/global/Oracle-Net-19c-Easy-Connect-Plus.pdf) syntax used below (`wallet_location` is the dir containing the cwallet.sso file), or by editing sqlnet.ora (or putting it in a default location).  See [How to connect to Oracle Autonomous Cloud Databases](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/how-connect-to-oracle-autonomous-cloud-databases).

Code that works for me is:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$c = oci_connect('cj', 'topsecret', 'tcps://adb.ap-melbourne-1.oraclecloud.com:1522/xxxxxx.adb.oraclecloud.com?wallet_location=/Users/cjones/Cloud/alwaysfree/CJDBMELB');

if (!$c) {
    $m = oci_error();
    trigger_error('Could not connect to database: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

$s = oci_parse($c, "select * from dual");
if (!$s) {
    $m = oci_error($c);
    trigger_error('Could not parse statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

$r = oci_execute($s);
if (!$r) {
    $m = oci_error($s);
    trigger_error('Could not execute statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "<td>";
        echo $item!==null?htmlspecialchars($item, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE):"&nbsp;";
        echo "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

Comment: The Oracle in the cloud solution is coming from a third-party vendor and we are being told that we won't have direct access to our password, but will be given access to a wallet that stores the credentials.  In the first meeting they remoted into one of our development servers and installed a wallet.  I can make a connection using command  line tools, but php balks because of the OCI_CRED_EXT flag on the call.  If the credentials are in the wallet and I supply a different password in the call, would it blow up or ignore the supplied pw in favor of the stored?  I'll have to try tomorrow.